# Android sys.powerctl property

Tags: android, properties, kernel, reboot

I'm looking for the info regarding sys.powerctl property.
I tried to set the property from shell:

**# setprop sys.powerctl reboot**

which performed reboot as expected.

I couldn't find more info regarding the property:

1. Who issues reboot when the property is set?
2. Is such reboot "safe" in kernel level?
3. Is it "safe" in android level?
4. What other values the property can accept

It's been a week, is it real no one has an answer... :-(

Answer (score 0):

it's kernel responsibility to turn device off once this property is changed

Check this blog for details:
http://blog.csdn.net/hovan/article/details/42495379

Comment: You can see the definition of do_powerctl here: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_system_core/blob/nougat-mr2-release/init/builtins.cpp#L695

Comment: It is actually the init process that monitors the process and then uses the shutdown syscall to reboot the system